# uwsgi + python2.7 unable to import anything

Tags: django, python-2.7, uwsgi

I'm trying to use uwsgi + python2.7 + django + nginx on debian 6.
I installed uwsgi with the command: `pip2.7 install uwsgi` so it's running with python 2.7.
I'm running uwsgi in emperor mode with the command:
uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals/ -d /var/log/uwsgi.log --pidfile /var/run/uwsgi.pid

The vassals folder contains only one app for the moment. Here is it's yaml file:

```
uwsgi:
    socket: /home/uwsgi/uwsgi/uwsgi.sock
    virtualenv: /opt/myproj/virt
    pythonpath: /home/uwsgi/project/my_proj
    pidfile: /home/uwsgi/uwsgi/uwsgi.pid
    uid: uwsgi
    gid: uwsgi
    chmod-socket: 1
    module: wsgi_app
    daemonize:  /home/uwsgi/uwsgi/uwsgi.log
    harakiri-verbose: 1
```

This is the content of the Django project file:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
SITE_DIR = '/home/uwsgi/project/my_proj'
import site
site.addsitedir(SITE_DIR)

import os
import sys
sys.path.append(SITE_DIR)

sys.path.append('/home/uwsgi/project/')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'my_proj.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Now, here is the result in the /home/uwsgi/uwsgi/uwsgi.log file when I try to launch it:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 1.0.4 (32bit) on [Fri Mar  2 19:00:46 2012] ***
compiled with version: 4.6.2 on 02 March 2012 18:03:07
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/vassals
writing pidfile to /home/uwsgi/uwsgi/uwsgi.pid
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
setgid() to 1001
setuid() to 1001
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
chmod() socket to 666 for lazy and brave users
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /home/uwsgi/uwsgi/uwsgi.sock fd 3
Python version: 2.7.2+ (default, Dec  1 2011, 02:17:49)  [GCC 4.6.2]
Set PythonHome to /opt/myproj/virt
ImportError: No module named site
*** Starting uWSGI 1.0.4 (32bit) on [Fri Mar  2 19:00:47 2012] ***
compiled with version: 4.6.2 on 02 March 2012 18:03:07
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/vassals
writing pidfile to /home/uwsgi/uwsgi/uwsgi.pid
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
setgid() to 1001
setuid() to 1001
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
chmod() socket to 666 for lazy and brave users
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /home/uwsgi/uwsgi/uwsgi.sock fd 3
Python version: 2.7.2+ (default, Dec  1 2011, 02:17:49)  [GCC 4.6.2]
Set PythonHome to /opt/myproj/virt
ImportError: No module named site
```

As you can see, uwsgi can't import the site module so uwsgi keeps trying to restart the app.
So I tried to add the no-site :1 option in the yaml file. The result is that I can't import anything in my Django project file...

I also know it's not linked to the project because if I run uwsgi with python 2.6, it just works fine... Unfortunally, I have to run it with python2.7...

Do you have any idea what happens ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Be sure your virtualenv is built for python2.7, otherwise it cannot be used.

It has to contains /opt/myproj/virt/lib/python2.7 directory

Comment: It's now debugged.
The problem was that the script I used to install the virtualenv was depricated.
It installed the python tools with pip instead of pip-2.7.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but... how can I close the ticket?

Comment: @user1187797 you vote the answer you like the most as the best answer.

Comment: yeah and select answer with a tick!